# Sound Issues after Installing GeForce GTX 960 + Chipmunks

Tags: audio, graphics-card, power-supply, speakers, nvidia-geforce

**EDIT:**

***I have tried installing a Nady HE-1 Hum Eliminator so as to deal with the buzz. Unfortunately, this had no effect when connected to the speakers via the front audio output, and had minimal effect when connected via the rear audio output. Also, Audio ONLY WORKS if both the front and rear outputs are plugged in. Somethings tells me there is more going on here than just a simple ground loop. More information below.***

I recently installed a GeForce GTX-960 Graphics card on my machine. The card was pretty bulky, and so it necessitated a move to a bigger case to make everything fit. I also have a standard old 1024x768 Resolution VGA Monitor. (It's fairly old. I've had it since about 2004/2005-ish, I believe.)

After installing the graphics card and getting everything set up, I started experiencing the following sound issues:

1. The speakers plugged into the rear 3.5mm jack suddenly exhibit hissing static when they used to be perfectly quiet, even when set at their highest levels. The speakers themselves are a set of high quality Altec Lansing Speakers, with a subwoofer. They're not really the cheapo kind you get as an afterthought, if that helps.
2. The rear 3.5mm jack speakers (the Altec Lansing ones) don't play any sound unless I have connected some headphones or (I assume) some other playback device into the front 3.5mm jack. And then it plays audio through both the front and rear speakers unless I manually turn the Altec Lansing speakers off.
3. On startup, there is usually a series of windows desktop notifications repeating the same two messages over for a bit: "You Just plugged a device into the audio jack", "You just unplugged a device from the audio jack", "You just plugged a device into the audio jack", etc, etc, back and forth for a bit.
4. Microphone input on both Skype and Open Broadcaster Software (OBS), ends up sped up and sounding like a chipmunk. The same issue happens when using Microsoft Sound Recorder, so I think it's pretty much system wide.

Some Additional Thoughts:

Installation of the Graphics card required that I upgrade my power supply unit from a 300 Watt psu to a 600 Watt psu. I don't know if that's relevant, but hopefully the added information will help. I also installed two additional hard drives during the migration to a new case.

I've been using the VGA adapter that come with the Graphics Card to connect to the Monitor. Currently, upgrading my monitor to accept HDMI input is outside the scope of my budget.

Other than that, I'm really at a loss for how to fix this. I've been researching stuff on google, but so far I haven't been able to find anything matching closely enough to my situation, and typing all of this into the search panel just ends up yielding zero results. D:

Thank you for any help received, and any time spent on this. I'm grateful.

Comment: Did you ensure that the board is properly isolated from the case via the appropriate standoffs and that any and all standoffs and screws are aligned properly and not making *unintended* contact with the motherboard? My gut says there is an "improper path to ground" (or worse). Have you used washers on the metalized holes?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jSA2F1AwboU has a good illustration of ground loop noise: easily described as a hissing static

Comment: Thank you, @Yorik. That youtube video was most helpful, though it did take a while for me to get a hum eliminator. Unfortunately, I'm afraid this hasn't worked. Something else is wrong. I will be editing the post to include additional information. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a microphone jack enabled "Listen to this device" under control panel > sound > recording (or is it microphones?) tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the issue remained unresolved. I followed the links that @Yorik gave on solving ground loop noise. Unfortunately, the addition of a Hum Eliminator seems to have made the problem worse, as all sound information coming out of the speakers was irreparably damaged and garbled.

After much research on google and elsewhere, I did come across large quantities of posts elsewhere that described similar symptoms, though none matched each other exactly, and none were ever successfully resolved. As far as I can tell, in all cases the issue stemmed with the on board sound chip and/or firmware simply deciding to go crazy and glitch constantly for no apparent reason.

I replaced the motherboard and purchased a new processor and ram sticks to go with it, thus eliminating the problem all together.